# Deleting remote branches

Tags: git, github

While using `git branch -a`, I saw that my repo contains a lot of branches with 'remotes/origin/' right in front, eg. remotes/origin/feature/Issue01

Then I saw that the repo also do have several few similar/same naming such as 'remotes/origin/remotes/origin/feature/Issue01', double 'remotes/origin' in the naming.

While I know that I can use this command `git push origin :<name of the branch>` to delete the branch, but in such cases, how can I tell if I am deleting the correct branch? (I wanted to get rid those with double remotes/origin naming...

Comment: Try "full branch name", i.e. `git push origin :refs/heads/remotes/origin/remotes/origin/feature/Issue01`. Do you have any idea where these weird names come from?

Comment: Some of them are created by me where I was using this command `git checkout -b remotes/origin/feature/Issue01 remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` and hence the result in double 'remotes/origin'. I was using the method wrongly and hence the need to cleanup now

Answer (score 2):

There are several items here that can be a bit tricky.

First, "remote branch" (as in the title of your question here) is at best ambiguous.  Do you mean the *remote-tracking branch* name in your repository, or the (regular, local) branch name in the Git repository stored on the remote?

Second, all branch names (local and remote-tracking) are specific forms of Git's more general *references*.  A local branch name like `master` or `feature/Issue01` is really just a reference whose name starts with `refs/heads/`: these two names are short for `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/feature/Issue01`, respectively.  A remote-tracking branch name like `origin/master` is just the short form of the full name `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

It's the prefix—the `refs/heads/` or `refs/remotes/` part—that tells Git which *group* the name belongs to.  Once Git has figured out the group (local branch name, remote-tracking branch name, and so on), Git tends to drop the prefix, so that you see just `master` and `origin/master`.  Sometimes Git drops only the `refs/` part, as in this output from `git branch -a` on a copy of the repository for Git itself:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  precious
  stash-exp
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/maint
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/next
  remotes/origin/pu
  remotes/origin/todo
```

If you manage to create confusing names, like a local branch whose *full* name is `refs/heads/origin/master`, everything gets very confusing: is `origin/master` this local branch, or is it the remote-tracking branch whose full name is `refs/remotes/origin/master`?

#### If you're in this confusing situation, spell everything out completely.

If you write `refs/heads/origin/master`, we can tell you mean the local branch.

Getting *Git* to use the full name is just a little bit harder.  The easy way is to use a "plumbing" command that does not try to abbreviate.  Thus, you can use the command `git for-each-ref`.  Run on its own, with no additional arguments, it simply prints *every* reference with its hash value, target object type, and full name:

```
$ git for-each-ref
bbc61680168542cf6fd3ae637bde395c73b76f0f commit refs/heads/master
f247a4de65f24e5f924d097843894bf839d34ac6 commit refs/heads/precious
93df9a13560851eaa088f76d71a95a96c6902188 commit refs/heads/stash-exp
a28705da929ad746abcb34270947f738549d3246 commit refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
0b65a8dbdb38962e700ee16776a3042beb489060 commit refs/remotes/origin/maint
a28705da929ad746abcb34270947f738549d3246 commit refs/remotes/origin/master
6bd575154409f30ff65ca6ef24fc65deb942bab4 commit refs/remotes/origin/next
a83f22757e2811817565ce1064edcffb40eeb213 commit refs/remotes/origin/pu
2d30c169da9a8b402b36a0b24689330559ca8943 commit refs/remotes/origin/todo
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86 tag    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
33682a5e98adfd8ba4ce0e21363c443bd273eb77 tag    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1
[lots more tags, snipped]
```

You can *delete* a local branch like `refs/heads/origin/master` with `git branch -d origin/master` (add `-f` or `--force`, or use `-D`, to forcibly delete the branch name, even if it's not merged), or you can rename it with `git branch -m` and give it a name that is not so confusing.  In all of these cases, omit the `refs/heads/`, since `git branch` already knows this means a (regular, local) branch.

You can even delete a remote-tracking branch like `refs/remotes/origin/remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` with `git branch -r -d`, but you do not need to, and probably should not bother, because:

#### Dealing with the remote Git

All of the above is fine for dealing with your own repository, but you also have another repository on another machine.  If that other machine is one you control directly, you can just log in there: use `ssh` to log in, `cd` to the place with the repository, and deal with just like you did with your own repository.  But what if you can't do that?

When the other machine is "in the cloud", it's often some computer you do not control, that you access through GitHub, for instance.  In this case, you may have some sort of web interface you can use—but you also have Git's standard mechanisms for accessing remotes.

The `git for-each-ref` that we ran above, to see what branches, remote-tracking branches, and tags we have, has a counterpart: `git ls-remote origin` contacts your remote named `origin` and basically runs `git for-each-ref` there.  That lets you see what they have.

Once you know the full name of each reference, you can delete (but not rename) the reference with `git push`, using the syntax you quoted above.  For instance, this:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/remotes/origin/feature/Issue01
```

asks the remote named `origin` to delete its local branch (`refs/heads/`) named `remotes/origin/feature/Issue01`.

You can also spell this `git push origin --delete` (or just `-d`).  If you have a large number of refs to delete, this is a little bit easier to type:

```
git push origin -d refs/heads/bad/name/one refs/heads/bad/name/two
```

Again, you can spell them out in full to eliminate ambiguity.

#### Using `git remote prune` or `git fetch -p`

Once you have deleted the (local) branch `refs/heads/remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` from the `origin` repository, you still have to get rid of the remote-tracking branch `refs/remotes/origin/remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` from your own repository.  Again, you can use `git branch -r -d`, but there is an easier way.

Just as `git fetch origin` *creates* remote-tracking branches in your repository, based on the names that spilled out of `git ls-remote origin`, `git fetch origin --prune` *removes* remote-tracking branches from your repository, based on these same names.

That is, after doing the equivalent of `git ls-remote origin`, *your* Git knows that there is now no `refs/heads/remotes/origin/feature/Issue01` on `origin`.  With `--prune`, you can tell your Git to remove the corresponding remote-tracking branch.

In some versions of Git, `git fetch --prune origin` was slightly defective, and `git remote prune origin` worked.  This *should* do pretty much the same thing, but if `git fetch --prune` is not working, try `git remote prune`.